# File named zero

Tags: macos

I've got a lot of files named `0` all over the place on my filesystem. They contain some digits (mostly also zeroes) inside.

I'am wondering what they are and where they came from? I'm running OS X Lion Developer Preview 3, but I'm not sure if that's the case.

Comment: Many terminal scripts and unix commands use `0` as the exit status to indicate that they ran successfully. Is it possible that you've somehow ended up redirecting the output from shell scripts or unix commands to empty files? I know I end up with misdirected output occasionally. Are they ending up in your home folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try running the command

```
sudo dtrace -qn 'syscall::open:entry /arg1&O_CREAT/ {printf("%5d %s file:%s\n",pid,execname,copyinstr(arg0));}' | grep '[:/]0$'
```

in a terminal window. The `dtrace` output will list the process ID, process name, and filename argument for any `open()` call with the `O_CREAT` flag set, meaning it will create the file if it does not already exist. Drop the final grep bit if you want to see all potentially file creating `open()` calls, but then the output might possibly overwhelm you. Hit ctrl-C when you're done with it.

If something keeps creating files named `0`, the culprit ought to show up in the output.

(Edit: Fixed the grep invocation.)